# Speeding up numpy.dot

Tags: python, performance, numpy, dot-product

I've got a `numpy` script that spends about 50% of its runtime in the following code:

`s = numpy.dot(v1, v1)`

where

`v1 = v[1:]`

and `v` is a 4000-element 1D `ndarray` of `float64` stored in contiguous memory (`v.strides` is `(8,)`).

Any suggestions for speeding this up?

**edit** This is on Intel hardware. Here is the output of my `numpy.show_config()`:

```
atlas_threads_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'ptf77blas', 'ptcblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/atlas-3.9.16/lib']
    language = f77
    include_dirs = ['/usr/local/atlas-3.9.16/include']

blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['ptf77blas', 'ptcblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/atlas-3.9.16/lib']
    define_macros = [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"3.9.16\\""')]
    language = c
    include_dirs = ['/usr/local/atlas-3.9.16/include']

atlas_blas_threads_info:
    libraries = ['ptf77blas', 'ptcblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/atlas-3.9.16/lib']
    language = c
    include_dirs = ['/usr/local/atlas-3.9.16/include']

lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'ptf77blas', 'ptcblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/atlas-3.9.16/lib']
    define_macros = [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"3.9.16\\""')]
    language = f77
    include_dirs = ['/usr/local/atlas-3.9.16/include']

lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

Comment: Care to give timing results? FWIW, in my modest machine dot(., .) with random vector of shape (4000,) will take some 6us. Thanks

Comment: @eat: The same operation on my machine takes under 5us. I am doing **a lot** of these though, and they add up.

Comment: Well, single `dot` seems then to be reasonable efficient. However, if you like to show more code us, someone might be able to find out how to optimize the calculations. Thanks

Comment: @tillsten: Yes, thanks, it's several times slower (probably due to its  use of a temporary array.)

Comment: yeah, should have tried it out myself first

Comment: @NPE, I didn't understand what the answer was. I ran into similar problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609475/numpy-dot-peformance-difference-between-linux-and-windows) and I'd like to know how you figured it out

Comment: @OferHelman: This was quite a long time ago (3.5 years), and I am sorry to say that I don't quite remember. :-( I do, however, seem to remember that I ended up using Intel MKL. Whether it did anything for this particular issue I am not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your arrays are not very big, so ATLAS probably isn't doing much.  What are your timings for the following Fortran program?  Assuming ATLAS isn't doing much, this should give you a sense of how fast dot() could be if there was not any python overhead.  With gfortran -O3 I get speeds of 5 +/- 0.5 us.

```
    program test

    real*8 :: x(4000), start, finish, s
    integer :: i, j
    integer,parameter :: jmax = 100000

    x(:) = 4.65
    s = 0.
    call cpu_time(start)
    do j=1,jmax
        s = s + dot_product(x, x)
    enddo
    call cpu_time(finish)
    print *, (finish-start)/jmax * 1.e6, s

    end program test
```

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps the culprit is copying of the arrays passed to *dot*.

As Sven said, the *dot* product relies on BLAS operations. These operations require arrays stored in contiguous C order. If both arrays passed to *dot* are in C_CONTIGUOUS, you ought to see better performance.

Of course, if your two arrays passed to dot are indeed 1D (8,) then you should see *both* the C_CONTIGUOUS AND F_CONTIGUOUS flags set to True; but if they are (1, 8), then you can see mixed order.

```
>>> w = NP.random.randint(0, 10, 100).reshape(100, 1)
>>> w.flags
   C_CONTIGUOUS : True
   F_CONTIGUOUS : False
   OWNDATA : False
   WRITEABLE : True
   ALIGNED : True
   UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

An alternative: use _GEMM from BLAS, which is exposed through the module, ***scipy.linalg.fblas***. (The two arrays, A and B, are obviously in Fortran order because *fblas* is used.)

```
from scipy.linalg import fblas as FB
X = FB.dgemm(alpha=1., a=A, b=B, trans_b=True)
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the input array is 1D (and the output is a scalar).

Answer (score 4):

Only thing I can think of to accelerate this is to make sure your NumPy installation is compiled against an optimized BLAS library (like ATLAS).  `numpy.dot()` is one of only a few NumPy functions that make use of BLAS.

Comment: Good suggestion (+1). I've updated the question with my `numpy` config. It does appear to have been built against ATLAS.

Comment: @aix: Your config looks fine to me (though I'm not really sure how to interpret it :)  On second thought, when your code spends most of its time multiplying medium sized vectors, you are probably operating at the the limits of memory bandwidth, so any optimization will only achieve that the processors waits even longer for new data.

Answer (score 3):

numpy.dot will use multithreading if compiled correctly. Make sure that it does with top. I know of cases where people didn't get multithreading in numpy w/ atlas to work. Furthermore, it's worth trying to use a numpy version that is compiled against the intel mkl libraries. They include blas routines that are supposed to be faster than atlas on intel hardware. You could give enthought's python distro a try. Contains all this and is free for people with an edu email account.

Comment: can you provide a link where we can get a numpy version that is compiled against the intel mkl libraries?

Comment: anaconda does that typically