# Does the performance of numpy differ depending on the operating system?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, memory

Reading the interesting book ["From Python to Numpy"](https://www.labri.fr/perso/nrougier/from-python-to-numpy/) I met an [example](https://www.labri.fr/perso/nrougier/from-python-to-numpy/#id4), the description of which is as follows:

> Let's consider a simple example where we want to clear all the values
>   from an array which has the dtype `np.float32`. How does one write it
>   to maximize speed?

The provided results surprised me, and when I rechecked them I got a completely different behavior. So, I asked the author to double-check, but he received the same results as before (*OS X 10*) in the table below:

The variants were timed on three different computers: mine (*Win10*, *Win7*) and author's (*OSX 10.13.3*). With *Python 3.6.4* and *numpy 1.14.2*, where each variant was timed for fixed *100 loops, best of 3*.

*Edit: This question is not about the fact that on different computers, with different characteristics, I get different times - this is obvious :) **The question is that the behavior is very different on the two operating systems - which is not so obvious?** (if it is of course so, I would be glad if someone could double-check).*

The setup was: `Z = np.ones(4*1000000, np.float32)`

```
| Variant                     | Windows 10 | Ubuntu 17.10 | Windows 7 | OSX 10.13.3 |
|                             |       computer 1          |   comp 2  |    comp 3   |
| --------------------------- | ------------------------- | --------- | ----------- |
| Z.view(np.float64)[...] = 0 | 758 usec   | 1.03 msec    | 2.72 msec | 1.01 msec   |
| Z.view(np.float32)[...] = 0 | 757 usec   | 1.01 msec    | 2.61 msec | 1.58 msec   |
| Z.view(np.float16)[...] = 0 | 760 usec   | 1.01 msec    | 2.62 msec | 2.85 msec   |
| Z.view(np.complex)[...] = 0 | 1.06 msec  | 1.02 msec    | 3.26 msec | 918 usec    |
| Z.view(np.int64)[...] = 0   | 758 usec   | 1.03 msec    | 2.69 msec | 1 msec      |
| Z.view(np.int32)[...] = 0   | 757 usec   | 1.01 msec    | 2.62 msec | 1.46 msec   |
| Z.view(np.int16)[...] = 0   | 760 usec   | 1.01 msec    | 2.63 msec | 2.87 msec   |
| Z.view(np.int8)[...] = 0    | 758 usec   | 773 usec     | 2.68 msec | 614 usec    |
| Z.fill(0)                   | 747 usec   | 998 usec     | 2.55 msec | N/A         |
| Z[...] = 0                  | 750 usec   | 1 msec       | 2.59 msec | N/A         |
```

As you can see from this table, on *Windows* the results doesn't depend on the viewed type, but on *OS X* this hack highly affects the performance. ***Can you provide the insight why this happens?***

***Edit***: As I wrote above three computers are different.

***The specs of the first computer***:
Windows 10  and Ubuntu 17.10
CPU: Intel Xenon E5-1650v4 3.60GHz
RAM: 128GB DDR4-2400

***The specs of the second computer***:
Windows 7
CPU: Intel Pentium P6100 2.00GHz
RAM: 4GB DDR3-1333

***The specs of the third computer***:
I don't have this information :)

[**Link to the issue**](https://github.com/rougier/from-python-to-numpy/issues/29)

***Edit 2***: Add results for the **first computer** on *Ubuntu 17.10*.

Comment: What are the compiler and versions for the different systems?

Comment: Unless you test the same code execution with the same hardware, i would be rather surprised if there were no difference.

Comment: Pretty pointless to compare different CPUs and think, the difference comes from the OS.

Comment: @user1767754 Fair point but not relevant hear. It seems that it is os-dependent behavior, because the results among two totally different computers are consistent on one OS but not with another OS.

Comment: @Daniel I compared `numpy` from three sources, the results are the same. 1. `pip` install from wheel (I think mingw64). 2. gohlke's version (Visual C++ 2017). 3. `intel-numpy` from PyPi (icc)

Comment: But hardware **does** matter.  It all comes down to the hardware in the end.

Comment: @Simon I do not argue, of course it matters. That's why I've asked a question so that you can double-check, I do not mind, I am interested by myself. But having obtained two consistent results on two computers (which I have) with different specs, I began to doubt that the issue comes from this part.

Comment: So where are the numbers with the same computer with two different OSes? You did not show them, yet.

Comment: This sounds like a difference of what instructions were available or what instructions the compilers picked, not an OS thing.

Comment: @Daniel When I wrote this question, I was mentally ready for this type of repetitive question. I don't have another OS right now, but tomorrow I will install some Linux distro and recheck. But I have no idea where to find OSX. If you have the opportunity to compare, I would be happy. But until tomorrow I can't give you new information :)

Comment: @user1767754 added results obtained on the first computer on Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: @Daniel added results obtained on the first computer on Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: @godaygo: Now you should use intel-numpy on each system to eliminate compiler effects.

Comment: The speed achieved in zeroing an array depends heavily on the handful of instructions selected by the compiler for the inner loop in each case. It's not at all surprising that different compilers would give very different results. Another big variable is how large arrays are allocated. In some library/OS combinations, physical pages aren't mapped until the memory is written. If that's happening in this case, the cost of page mapping is being paid as part of the zeroing. It would be more realistic to "warm up" the array by writing it once before measuring (if the author didn't do that).

Answer (score 10):

Keep in mind that Python is a very high-level programming language, Pandas being also a high-level framework.

What you're essentially given to work with is a high level API for many operations that you can perform with the language, without the need to worry about the underlying implementation.

If you were to work with a lower-level API, to assign an array to a variable you'd have to allocate some memory, create a structure to hold your data, link it together (probably using pointers to memory addresses). And you didn't even touch the actual chip, there's still virtual memory mapping being done between your API and the actual data being saved to the chip. And that complexity is applied to basically everything you're doing with Python & Pandas.

Yet, you only have to do `arr = [1, 2, 3]`, and not worry about it.

Now Python is expected to work the same on every platform you run it - at least in most of the cases.

Now, after the boring introduction is behind us - the whole idea of "expose uniform API, don't worry about implementation" is widely spread in computer programming. There are some subtle implementation details that differ one operating system from another, which may or may not impact performance of your software. I don't expect that to be significant, but it's still there and worth mentioning.

For example, there's an [old answer about `np.dot` function performance differing between Linux and Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26617725/3607501). The author has way more knowledge than me on this subject, and points out that that particular function is a wrapper around CBLAS routines, which will use fastest routines available on given platform.

That being said - pandas is a very complex library which aims to make data analysis as simple as possible, through exposing simple-to-use API to the programmer. I expect that there are a lot more places where Pandas does a great job using the best mechanisms available on your platform to perform its tasks as fast as it can.