# Calculation of sales with a dataframe takes too long

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a problem. I would like to calculate the turnover for a customer in the last 6 months. The methods work on my dummy record, unfortunately the whole thing does not work on my real record as it is too slow. How can I rewrite this so that it performs faster?

Dataframe

```py
   customerId   fromDate  sales
0           1 2022-06-01    100
1           1 2022-05-25     20
2           1 2022-05-25     50
3           1 2022-05-20     30
4           1 2021-09-05     40
5           2 2022-06-02     80
6           3 2021-03-01     50
7           3 2021-02-01     20
```

Code

```py
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

import pandas as pd


def find_last_date(date_: datetime) -> datetime:
    six_months = date_ + relativedelta(months=-6)
    return six_months


def sum_func(row: pd.DataFrame, df: pd.DataFrame) -> int :
    return df[
            (df["customerId"] == row["customerId"])
             & (row["fromDate"] + relativedelta(months=-6)<= df["fromDate"])
             & (df["fromDate"]   <= row["fromDate"])
        ]["sales"].sum()

d = {
    "customerId": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3],
    "fromDate": [
        "2022-06-01",
        "2022-05-25",
        "2022-05-25",
        "2022-05-20",
        "2021-09-05",
        "2022-06-02",
        "2021-03-01",
        "2021-02-01",
    ],
    "sales": [100, 20, 50, 30, 40, 80, 50, 20],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df["fromDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["fromDate"], errors="coerce")
df["last_month"] = df["fromDate"].apply(find_last_date)
df["total_sales"]=df[["customerId", "fromDate"]].apply(lambda x: sum_func(x, df), axis=1)
print(df)
```

What I want

```py
   customerId   fromDate  sales last_month total_sales
0           1 2022-06-01    100 2022-03-01        200 # 100 + 20 + 50 + 30
1           1 2022-05-25     20 2022-02-25        100 # 20 + 50 + 30
2           1 2022-05-25     50 2022-02-25        100 # 50 + 20 + 30
3           1 2022-05-20     30 2022-02-20        30  # 30
4           1 2021-09-05     40 2021-06-05        40  # 40
5           2 2022-06-02     80 2022-03-02        80  # 80
6           3 2021-03-01     50 2020-12-01        70  # 50 + 20
7           3 2021-02-01     20 2020-11-01        20  # 20
```

---

`print(df['customerId'].value_counts().describe())`

```py
count    53979.000
mean        87.404
std       1588.450
min          1.000
25%          2.000
50%          6.000
75%         22.000
max     205284.000
```

`print(df['fromDate'].agg((min, max)))`

```py
min   2021-02-22
max   2022-03-26
```

Comment: `last_month` is an offset of 3 months in your input not 6 months. First you can use `df["last_month"] = df["fromDate"] - pd.DateOffset(months=6)` and remove your `find_last_date` function.

Comment: Is it important to keep the day or is it possible to replace the day by 1 like "2022-05-25" becomes "2022-05-01"?

Comment: @Corralien thanks for the comment. It is important to keep the last day.

Comment: Ok. How many records do you have in your real case? (and how many distinct users)

Comment: @Corralien around 3 mio and unique customerIds ~75k

Comment: Does the answer give correct performance?

Comment: @Corralien Unfortunately not. I got an `MemoryError`

Comment: Have you considered using Dask? And eventually you can considering partitioning your data in a suitable way.

Comment: @Corralien sure, please see my edit.

Comment: The memory error is probably due to the customerId who have 205284 records because for the solution based on `groupby`, you need to build an array of 205284x205284 so 42,141,520,656 records.

Comment: Another question: what is the output of `print(df['fromDate'].agg((min, max)))`?

Comment: @Corralien  Thank you, is there another option to calculate this then?

Comment: I'm thinking about it :) It depends on my last question.

Comment: @Corralien that is the output: `min 2021-02-22` and `max 2022-03-26`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using multiprocessing and consider 6 months as 180 days to reduce the memory size and the time computing.

Copy the following code to a python file and run it from the console (not from a Jupyter Notebook)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def sum_sales(customer, df):
    # 1st pass: sum sales of same days, reduce the row numbers
    df1 = df.groupby('fromDate')['sales'].sum()

    # Generate all missing dates
    df1 = df1.reindex(pd.date_range(df1.index.min(), df1.index.max(), freq='D'), fill_value=0)

    # 2nd pass: use a sliding window of 180 days to sum
    df1 = df1.rolling(90, min_periods=0).sum().astype(int)

    # Restore original index for the group
    df1 = df1.reindex(df['fromDate']).reset_index(drop=True).to_frame().set_index(df.index)

    return df1


if __name__ == '__main__':  # Do not remove this line! Mandatory
    # Setup a minimal reproducible example
    N = 3_000_000
    D = pd.to_datetime('2021-1-1')
    rng = np.random.default_rng(2022)
    dti = D + pd.to_timedelta(rng.integers(0, 365*2, N), unit='D')
    cust = rng.integers(0, 75000, N)
    sales = rng.integers(1, 200, N)
    df = pd.DataFrame({'customerId': cust, 'fromDate': dti, 'sales': sales})

    # Ensure your dataframe is sorted by fromDate for rolling window
    df.sort_values(['customerId', 'fromDate'], ignore_index=True)

    start = time.time()
    with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count() - 1) as p:
        results = p.starmap(sum_sales, df.groupby('customerId'))
    df['total_sales'] = pd.concat(results)
    end = time.time()
    print(f"Elapsed time: {end - start:.2f} seconds")
```

For 3mio records and 75k different customers on 2 years (730 days)

```
[...]$ python mp.py
Elapsed time: 24.36 seconds
```

However the number of sales per customer is well balanced than your:

```
>>> df['customerId'].value_counts().describe(percentiles=np.linspace(0, 1, 11)
count    75000.000000
mean        40.000000
std          6.349157
min         15.000000
0%          15.000000
10%         32.000000
20%         35.000000
30%         37.000000
40%         38.000000
50%         40.000000
60%         41.000000
70%         43.000000
80%         45.000000
90%         48.000000  # <- check the 90th percentile of your data
100%        73.000000
max         73.000000  # <- max transactions for a single customer
Name: customerId, dtype: float64
```

Because the sales are properly distributed per customer, my sample takes advantage of multiprocessing. In your case, I don't think it will be the case (check the 90th percentile).

The check with your dataframe:

```
>>> df
   customerId   fromDate  sales  total_sales
0           1 2022-06-01    100          200
1           1 2022-05-25     20          100
2           1 2022-05-25     50          100
3           1 2022-05-20     30           30
4           1 2021-09-05     40           40
5           2 2022-06-02     80           80
6           3 2021-03-01     50           70
7           3 2021-02-01     20           20
```

If you decide to choose to keep a variable moving window of 6 months instead of a fixed moving window of 180 days, the algorithm will me the same. The important point in the code is to reduce the number of rows per customer. In your sample, you can group the sales for a same (customer, date). The customer 1 have 2 rows for 2022-05-25 so you can sum them immediately.

IIUC, in your real data, you have a customer with 205284 sales between 2021-02-22 and 2022-03-26 (397 days), so this user has an average of 517 transactions per day (?). If you sum sales of same days, you reduce the number of records from 205284 to 397...

Comment: I ran it again on my data set and it worked without any problems. However, I get any result with a minus, e.g. `-2147483648`. Do you have any idea what this could be? I have no values smaller than `0.0` for `sales`. For `total_sales` are `179558` elements are small than `0.0`

Comment: For how many customerId, total_sales are lower than 0.0? Only 1 or many? `df[df['total_sales'] < 0].value_counts('customerId')`. Is it possible for your to share your data?

Comment: This is the following output of your question: `customerId  77382    96417 // 77375    83141`. I could create the csv file and where should I upload it?

Comment: You can use wetransfer or dropbox to upload your file. Did you explore the data for this 2 customers? Are you sure sales are all positive?

Comment: I was just about to create the record and wanted to test it again. However, I got an error message and simply removed all `NaN` values from `fromDate`. With this it ran without any problems and without a minus. I therefore have a faulty date format somewhere, which I must first clean up. Then it should run without any problems. Thank you very much for your answer and your efforts.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again. I have cleaned up everything, it is not the data. I have now also received errors with the data set. Could I send you my data set again so that you can have a look at it? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with your data? I ran my code and everything seems normal. You have 137027 rows where sales are 0, 48612 rows where customerId is -1. No negative values in total_sales. 1895 customerId where total_sales are always 0.

Comment: Thank you for the time. For example, I did `df['total_sales].describe()` at the end and get minus values for `mean` and `min`. I also see that some customers have minus values for `total_sales`.

Comment: `count    4.717989e+06`, `mean    -3.554474e+05`, `std      4.816665e+08`, `min     -2.147484e+09`

Comment: Could it be because I transform it into a `pd.to_datetime` `df["fromDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["fromDate"], errors="coerce")`? If I omit this, I get `0` for `.describe()`.

Comment: Do you have the same result if you use: `df = pd.read_csv('customer.csv', parse_dates=['fromDate'], dtype={'customerId': str})`? My output for `df['total_sales].describe()` is `count    4.717989e+06
mean     2.423286e+08
std      8.662144e+08
min      0.000000e+00`

Comment: No unfortunately :/. I got `count    4.717989e+06`
`mean    -3.554474e+05`
`std      4.816665e+08`
`min     -2.147484e+09`. What could be the reason for this? If I use the same method?
`

Comment: Have you changed anything else in your method? Or am I not doing it right? I read in the data frame normally and then I format `fromDate` with `pd.to_datetime()` and then it is 1:1 the same code as in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use numpy broadcasting per groups with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for set for `True` values of `Sales` and if not match `0`, so possible sum sales to new column:

```
df["fromDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["fromDate"], errors="coerce")
df["last_month"] = df["fromDate"] - pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=6)

def f(x):
    d1 = x["fromDate"].to_numpy()
    d2 = x["last_month"].to_numpy()
    mask = (d2[:, None]<=d1) & (d1<=d1[:, None])
    x['total_sales'] = np.dot(mask, x['sales'].to_numpy())
    return x

df = df.groupby('customerId').apply(f)

print(df)
   customerId   fromDate  sales last_month  total_sales
0           1 2022-06-01    100 2021-12-01          200
1           1 2022-05-25     20 2021-11-25          100
2           1 2022-05-25     50 2021-11-25          100
3           1 2022-05-20     30 2021-11-20           30
4           1 2021-09-05     40 2021-03-05           40
5           2 2022-06-02     80 2021-12-02           80
6           3 2021-03-01     50 2020-09-01           70
7           3 2021-02-01     20 2020-08-01           20
```

EDIT:

```
df["fromDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["fromDate"], errors="coerce")
df["last_month"] = df["fromDate"] - pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=6)

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/27670190/2901002
def chunking_dot(big_matrix, small_matrix, chunk_size=10000):
    # Make a copy if the array is not already contiguous
    small_matrix = np.ascontiguousarray(small_matrix)
    R = np.empty((big_matrix.shape[0], small_matrix.shape[1]))
    for i in range(0, R.shape[0], chunk_size):
        end = i + chunk_size
        R[i:end] = np.dot(big_matrix[i:end], small_matrix)
    return R

def f(x):
    d1 = x["fromDate"].to_numpy()
    d2 = x["last_month"].to_numpy()
    mask = (d2[:, None]<=d1) & (d1<=d1[:, None])
    # print (mask)

    x['total_sales'] = chunking_dot(mask, x[['sales']].to_numpy())

    return x

df = df.groupby('customerId').apply(f)
```

---

```
print(df)
   customerId   fromDate  sales last_month  total_sales
0           1 2022-06-01    100 2021-12-01        200.0
1           1 2022-05-25     20 2021-11-25        100.0
2           1 2022-05-25     50 2021-11-25        100.0
3           1 2022-05-20     30 2021-11-20         30.0
4           1 2021-09-05     40 2021-03-05         40.0
5           2 2022-06-02     80 2021-12-02         80.0
6           3 2021-03-01     50 2020-09-01         70.0
7           3 2021-02-01     20 2020-08-01         20.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I got an `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 52.7 GiB for an array with shape`. Is there an work around ?

Comment: @Test If remove `x['total_sales'] = np.where(mask, x['sales'],0).sum(axis=1)` still memory error? Only for testing if problem in np.where

Comment: without `x['total_sales'] = np.where(mask, x['sales'],0).sum(axis=1)` I got no error

Comment: @Test - if use `x['total_sales'] = (mask * x['sales'].to_numpy()).sum(axis=1)` instead `x['total_sales'] = np.where(mask, x['sales'],0).sum(axis=1)` it return error ?

Comment: @Test - I hope this working `x['total_sales'] = np.dot(mask, x['sales'].to_numpy())`

Comment: Thanks you. `x['total_sales'] = (mask * x['sales'].to_numpy()).sum(axis=1)` and `x['total_sales'] = np.dot(mask, x['sales'].to_numpy())` still got me the same error. :/

Comment: Could be the reason because I have `sales` with `0.000` ?

Comment: @Test - yes, it is possible. If `df['total_sales'] = df['total_sales'].astype(int)` it remove floats and convert to integers and it should working.

Comment: I changed it as `int` and also tried this `df['sales'] = df['sales'].astype(np.uint8)`. The error still occurs

Comment: @Test - Can you check EDIT? I use `chunk_size=10000` change it by your real data

Comment: Thanks for your help. I appreciate it very much. I have tried myself with `chunk_size=100`. However, I still get a MemoryError :( sorry... Is there any possibility to calculate this step by step for example? Or are there other possibilities?

Comment: @Test - Is possible aggregate by days before processing my solution? Like `Corralien` mentioned. It means use `df.groupby(['customerId', 'fromDate'], as_index=False).sales.sum()` before my solution. It should reduce number of rows, so I hope no memory error. But ouput is different, e.g. in sample data are summed 2. and 3. row.