# Calculation of the sales returns minus values, although there are no minus values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, multiprocessing

I have a problem. I wanted to use the code snippet below to solve the following problem

> I would like to calculate the turnover for a customer in the last 6
> months.

Unfortunately, when I run the code I eventually get a minus value for a customer. So my `min` is in the minus range. This should not be the case. What could be the reason for this? I don't have a customer who has a minus amount. All are in the positive range. The example code seems to work.
Code is adapted from: [Calculation of sales with a dataframe takes too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72555346/calculation-of-sales-with-a-dataframe-takes-too-long)

Dataframe

```py
   customerId   fromDate  sales
0           1 2022-06-01    100
1           1 2022-05-25     20
2           1 2022-05-25     50
3           1 2022-05-20     30
4           1 2021-09-05     40
5           2 2022-06-02     80
6           3 2021-03-01     50
7           3 2021-02-01     20
```

Code

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def sum_sales(customer, df):
    # 1st pass: sum sales of same days, reduce the row numbers
    df1 = df.groupby('fromDate')['sales'].sum()

    # Generate all missing dates
    df1 = df1.reindex(pd.date_range(df1.index.min(), df1.index.max(), freq='D'), fill_value=0)

    # 2nd pass: use a sliding window of 180 days to sum
    df1 = df1.rolling(90, min_periods=0).sum().astype(int)

    # Restore original index for the group
    df1 = df1.reindex(df['fromDate']).reset_index(drop=True).to_frame().set_index(df.index)

    return df1


if __name__ == '__main__':  # Do not remove this line! Mandatory
    # Setup a minimal reproducible example
    N = 3_000_000
    D = pd.to_datetime('2021-1-1')
    rng = np.random.default_rng(2022)
    dti = D + pd.to_timedelta(rng.integers(0, 365*2, N), unit='D')
    cust = rng.integers(0, 75000, N)
    sales = rng.integers(1, 200, N)
    df = pd.DataFrame({'customerId': cust, 'fromDate': dti, 'sales': sales})

    # Ensure your dataframe is sorted by fromDate for rolling window
    df.sort_values(['customerId', 'fromDate'], ignore_index=True)

    start = time.time()
    with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count() - 1) as p:
        results = p.starmap(sum_sales, df.groupby('customerId'))
    df['total_sales'] = pd.concat(results)
    end = time.time()
    print(f"Elapsed time: {end - start:.2f} seconds")
```

What I got with my data set

```py
count    4.717989e+06
mean    -3.554474e+05
std      4.816665e+08
min     -2.147484e+09
```

What I want

```
   customerId   fromDate  sales last_month total_sales
0           1 2022-06-01    100 2022-03-01        200 # 100 + 20 + 50 + 30
1           1 2022-05-25     20 2022-02-25        100 # 20 + 50 + 30
2           1 2022-05-25     50 2022-02-25        100 # 50 + 20 + 30
3           1 2022-05-20     30 2022-02-20        30  # 30
4           1 2021-09-05     40 2021-06-05        40  # 40
5           2 2022-06-02     80 2022-03-02        80  # 80
6           3 2021-03-01     50 2020-12-01        70  # 50 + 20
7           3 2021-02-01     20 2020-11-01        20  # 20
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

```
s = df.groupby(['customerId', 'fromDate'])['sales'].sum()
s = s.reset_index('customerId').sort_index()
s = s.groupby('customerId').rolling('90d', min_periods=1).sum()
s = df.merge(s.add_prefix('total_').reset_index(), how='left')
```

#### Explained

Group the dataframe by `customerId` and `fromDate` and aggregate `sales` using `sum`

```
customerId  fromDate  
1           2021-09-05     40
            2022-05-20     30
            2022-05-25     70
            2022-06-01    100
2           2022-06-02     80
3           2021-02-01     20
            2021-03-01     50
Name: sales, dtype: int64
```

Reset the index level `customerId` and sort the `fromDate` level to make it monotonic as this is essential to do rolling calculations

```
            customerId  sales
fromDate                     
2021-02-01           3     20
2021-03-01           3     50
2021-09-05           1     40
2022-05-20           1     30
2022-05-25           1     70
2022-06-01           1    100
2022-06-02           2     80
```

Group the dataframe by `customerId` and calculate a `rolling` `sum` with a window of `90 days`

```
                       sales
customerId fromDate         
1          2021-09-05   40.0
           2022-05-20   30.0
           2022-05-25  100.0
           2022-06-01  200.0
2          2022-06-02   80.0
3          2021-02-01   20.0
           2021-03-01   70.0
```

Merge the above rolling sum with original dataframe

```
   customerId   fromDate  sales  total_sales
0           1 2022-06-01    100        200.0
1           1 2022-05-25     20        100.0
2           1 2022-05-25     50        100.0
3           1 2022-05-20     30         30.0
4           1 2021-09-05     40         40.0
5           2 2022-06-02     80         80.0
6           3 2021-03-01     50         70.0
7           3 2021-02-01     20         20.0
```

##### Additional notes

- Multiprocessing is not required if you are already using the vectorized methods, multiprocessing will add additional overhead and will slow things down.
- I can see that your existing logic is a bit overkill, as you don't need to `reindex` before using rolling, here you can simply pass the frequency as `90d` and rolling will automatically take care of adjusting the sliding window.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution runs through. However, I have an error, as soon as I run the code I get values like `max 7347423783.367` (for `s['total_sales].describe()`) while I have a customer who over the entire period only for `df.groupby(['customerId'])['netPrice'].describe() -> max 650205.513`. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: @Test `total_sales` is the rolling sum, so it might have the values greater than the individual values in `sales` column, but again the exact reason will be hard to guess without looking at the actual data.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thank you for the information. If a customer has several orders on the same day, is it possible to take only one of them?

Comment: @Test I think in that case instead of using `df.groupby(['customerId', 'fromDate'])['sales'].sum()` you can try : `df.groupby(['customerId', 'fromDate'])['sales'].first()` or maybe take the average of sales using `df.groupby(['customerId', 'fromDate'])['sales'].mean()`