# MemoryError when run numpy dot product on 2 million arrays

Tags: python, numpy, python-multiprocessing, large-data, cosine-similarity

### **Firstly,**

I have a large list, named  `phrases` ,which contain over 2 million keyphrases.

```
phrases=['artificial intelligence','task management','artificial intelligence method','neural network',...]

len(phrases)=2024595
```

### **Secondly,**

I want to entity alignment on `phrases` , my solution is alignment based on cosine similarity (grouping similar keyphrases according to threshold) .  
But when I run the code, it seems to report a `MemoryError`.
The cosine similarity is based on large-language-model, and encoding to 384 dimensions.

### **Thirdly,**

My python code are below :

```
from typing import List
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
from multiprocessing import Pool
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer



#load language-model
model_path = "/mnt/HuggingfaceModel/all-MiniLM-L6-v2"
model = SentenceTransformer(model_path)



# Define a function to find similar keyphrases for a given index
def find_similar_keyphrases(arg):
    index, similarity_matrix, keyphrases, threshold = arg
    similar_indices = np.where(similarity_matrix[index] >= threshold)[0]
    similar_keyphrases = [keyphrases[j] for j in similar_indices]
    return similar_keyphrases



# Define a function to group similar keyphrases together
def group_keyphrases(keyphrases: List[str], threshold: float) -> List[List[str]]:
    num_keyphrases = len(keyphrases)
    
    print('Encoding keyphrases...')
    # Encode all keyphrases into vectors
    keyphrase_embeddings = model.encode(keyphrases, batch_size=16)
    print('Encoding completed.')
    
    print('Calculating cosine similarity between all keyphrase embeddings...')
    # Calculate the cosine similarity between all pairs of keyphrase embeddings
    similarity_matrix = np.dot(keyphrase_embeddings, keyphrase_embeddings.T)
    similarity_matrix = np.triu(similarity_matrix, k=1)

    # Initialize a list to store the groups of similar keyphrases
    groups = []
    
    print('Finding similar keyphrases...')
    # Parallel processing to find similar keyphrases for each index
    with Pool(processes=6) as pool:
        args = [(i, similarity_matrix, keyphrases, threshold) for i in range(num_keyphrases)]
        results = pool.map(find_similar_keyphrases, args)

    # Iterate over each set of similar keyphrases and add them to an existing group or create a new group
    for similar_keyphrases in tqdm(results):
        group_found = False
        for group in groups:
            if any(keyphrase in group for keyphrase in similar_keyphrases):
                group.extend(similar_keyphrases)
                group_found = True
                break
        if not group_found:
            groups.append(similar_keyphrases)

    return groups



import time

start_time = time.time()

threshold = 0.9
keyphrases = phrases

keyphrase_groups = group_keyphrases(keyphrases, threshold)

end_time = time.time()
elapsed_time = end_time - start_time

print(f"Elapsed time: {elapsed_time:.2f} seconds")
```

Reported error are below :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      6 print('Calculating cosine similarity between all keyphrase embeddings...')
      7 # Calculate the cosine similarity between all pairs of keyphrase embeddings
----> 8 similarity_matrix = np.dot(keyphrase_embeddings, keyphrase_embeddings.T)
      9 similarity_matrix = np.triu(similarity_matrix, k=1)
     10 

<__array_function__ internals> in dot(*args, **kwargs)

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 14.9 TiB for an array with shape (2024595, 2024595) and data type float32
```

My device parameters are below :

- Available memory: 86 GB
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090  *  1
- CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8157 CPU @ 2.30GHz  *  12
- GPU Memory: 24 GB
- GPU Bandwidth: 936.10 GB/s
- Hard Drive: Samsung SSD 870
- Hard Drive Bandwidth: 662.43 MB/s

#### Is there any solution to the problem of huge RAM computing consumption ?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27668462/numpy-dot-memoryerror-my-dot-very-slow-but-works-why